# Creating a new worksheet duplicate with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Im currently working on a code in which I am creating a new worksheet for every "case" that gets entered using a command button. However, the worksheets that are being created are blank, and I would like them to duplicate another worksheet that is in my workbook (lets call it "template"). Does anybody have any knowledge on how to do this? I will be thankful for any input!

This is my code so far (i have added hyperlinks between the worksheets as well):

```
financing = ws.Range("F2").Value
compName = ws.Range("F3").Value
fortnr = compName & "-" & financing

lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Cells(lastRow, "B") = financing
ws.Cells(lastRow, "C") = compName


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = compName & "-" & financing
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Visible = xlSheetVisible

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(lastRow, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & fortnr & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Check"                                  'Anchor: the place where the link will be

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, "", Sheets("INPUT").Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Back to Input-sheet"

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking for [Worksheet.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Copy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the entire worksheet named "Template":

```
Sub Test()
    Worksheets("Template").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Template")
End Sub
```

Will create a copy named "Template (2)" left of "Template". Alternatively use `After:=` instead of `Before:=` to place it to the right.
When you omit the argument, it will copy to a new workbook.

Comment: Hi Rik,
Thanks for your tip. The problem that I am having is that the original "Template" worksheet disappears, and a new one is created "Template(2)" along with the the new duplicate worksheet (which I was looking to do). Then when trying to duplicate "Template" again for my next input, it doesn't work as it is now called "Template(2)". This is my code now:

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Name = compName & "-" & financing
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(compName & "-" & financing).Visible = xlSheetVisible

Comment: With the `.Copy` method, the original worksheet remains exactly where it is. It just gets copied and that's all. Can you give your entire code while using `.Copy` see we can see what's going wrong? Probably you're changing workbook references (`ActiveWorkbook`?)

Comment: @IBAndy You're first changing the name. Obviously on a second run you won't find that sheet anymore. You should do the Copy first, then do `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template (2)").Name = compName` etc. etc.

Comment: HBi Rik,
Sorry for my late reply. You are absolutely correct, a new worksheet gets produced with the name "Template(2)", along with the worksheet that I was hoping for. So now i have to somehow figure out how to keep the name in the "template" worksheet the same, instead of "template(2)".

Comment: When I add ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template (2)").Name = compName i get an error...This is my code so far:

Comment: Hi again Rik,
Figured it out. I forgot to put in a space between Template and (2). All sorted out, thanks again!

Comment: No worries happy to help